# Burninate print-to-file

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [print-to-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/print-to-file) tag (18 questions, no wiki) contains a mix of questions regarding "Print to file" dialogs on programs, detecting printer functionality and simple file I/O. As I see, there is no meaningful use which other, more established tags don't account for.

There is no way someone can be a expert at printing to files, without being a expert at file I/O, or printer devices (even software printers).

In short:

- It has multiple meanings
- Those meanings are covered in other tags
- It isn't any more specific

I suggest to remove it, retagging the questions to either [io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io) or [printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printing). In fact, most questions already have the related tag, so only removing [print-to-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/print-to-file) should do.

Comment: 18 questions? Just go ahead and do it, though consider what else might need doing on each.

Comment: @Deduplicator I would, but as per the burnination rules, only people who can retag without revision should. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191. I'll take a look at the worse ones when I get home. (@work)

Comment: Yeah, 2K+ rep. I'll take care of it.\

Comment: Okie, I went through all the posts, gave things that deserved io the io tag, gave things that deserved printing the printing tag, tidied up a few posts, and just removed the tag when I found no suitable replacement tags.

Comment: @Compass Great work!

Answer (score 2):

Big thanks to ***Compass***, who went trough the 18 questions and retagged appropriately!

---

So I guess I can say...

[image: BURNINATED!]

Comment: Well, it's only official when a mod verifies I am not insane and didn't willy-nilly delete tags like a robot.

Comment: Well, I can't accept this in 2 days, so let's home you're not insane 'till then!